# ASP:menu error occuring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting SCRIPT5009: WebForm_GetElementByTagName is undefined error when I have been using asp menu in IE 10 instead of IE 9 (which is earlier installed).

When I tried to find it I found this is occurring because when WebResource.axd is generated it does not have definition for this method.

On further findings I found .net does not recognizes IE 10 as in browser file its entry is missing.

So for this we have patch available which fixes this problem, however I want to add any javascript or code which will add defination for WebForm_GetElementByTagName orthat resolves error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman [covered this problem](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) some time ago. If you don't want to install the patch, you'll have to use the workaround suggested by Greg Smalter in the comments: set the [`Page.ClientTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx) to "uplevel", either in the `Page_Init` event or the `<%@ Page ... %>` directive.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and the Nuget package suggested by Scott Hanselman did the trick.